# Getting image URL after uploading to Imgur API using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, upload, alamofire, imgur

I am uploading images anonymously using the Imgur API and Alamofire. However, I am not getting the url in the response json. Here is my code:

```
    static func post(image: UIImage, for username: String) {

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64Image = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

    let url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload"

    let parameters = [
        "image": base64Image
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: username, fileName: "\(username).png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
        }}, to: url, method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "Client-ID " + Constants.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID],
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.response { response in
                        print(response) // url nowhere to be found
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print("error:\(encodingError)")
                }
    })

}
```

Here is the printed response:

[image]

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are just printing the `response` of the request, you actually need to parse that into `JSON` and than check the response of your request, it does contain the image url you just uploaded. 
This is how you should parse the `response` and get the image url.

```
static func post(image: UIImage, for username: String) {

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64Image = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

    let url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload"

    let parameters = [
        "image": base64Image
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: username, fileName: "\(username).png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
        }}, to: url, method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "Client-ID " + Constants.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID],
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.response { response in
                        //This is what you have been missing
                         let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                         print(json)
                         let imageDic = json?["data"] as? [String:Any]
                         print(imageDic?["link"])
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print("error:\(encodingError)")
                }
    })

}
```